# Wrapping a word in LaTeX

Tags: latex, word-wrap

**How can you wrap the word *longWord_anotherLongWord_long_again* to many lines in the tabular environment?**

The word should be

```
LongWord_
anotherLongWord_
long_again
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\bgroup
  \catcode`\_=13%
  \def_{\textunderscore\hskip0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{4.5cm}}
    test_444 & 555 & longWord_anotherLongWord_long_again_too_long_very_long_ha_ha_ha_ha\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\egroup
```

Be careful though; this will produce the desired result, but TeX will complain about underfull boxes.