# Wrapping multiple words concatenated with / symbols in latex tables

Tags: latex, special-characters, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a latex table, and I want to insert a string of the form word/anotherword/athirdword/afourthword/andsoon. This doesn't work though, as it will overflow instead of wrapping to the next line. If I just remove all the "/" characters, it works well. Below are some examples:

Correctly working word wrap without "/":

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{10em}|p{10em}|p{10em}| } 
        \hline
        a wordanotherwordathirdwordafourthwordandsoon & 
        Next column & 
        Third column \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Overflowing with "/":

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{10em}|p{10em}|p{10em}| } 
        \hline
        a word/anotherword/athirdword/afourthword/andsoon & 
        Next column & 
        Third column \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Another oddity, if I remove the first word "a" from the cell, the word overflows no matter what.

I tried to search SO for help, but the closest I was [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353098/wrapping-a-word-in-latex), which doesn't really address my problem.

EDIT: Here is the minimal reprex I mention in the comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{10em}|p{10em}|p{10em}| } 
        \hline
        a wordanotherwordathirdwordafourthwordandsoon & 
        Next column & 
        Third column \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{10em}|p{10em}|p{10em}| } 
        \hline
        a word/anotherword/athirdword/afourthword/andsoon & 
        Next column & 
        Third column \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can help latex by adding possible hyphenation points, e.g. `first\-word`

Comment: and please make a compilable [mre] that reproduces your problem and not juts code fragments

Comment: I guess that works. It feels a little "brute force", but it fixes my problem, so thanks!

Comment: Also, sorry for not providing a minimal reproducible example. I have edited my post, does the code under "minimal reprex" satisfy that`?